# Loads viewcontroller but does'nt present until second tap on tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

When i tap my tableview this code gets executed:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        ViewController *vc =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        vc.currentCategory = indexPath.row ;
        [self presentViewController: vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Everything seems to load and it breaks on the breakpoints in the new viewcontroller. But it doesnt get presented. If i tap a second time it does'nt execute the code but it presents the viewcontroller. If i go animated: NO, everything works on the first tap, but not with animated: YES. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Do you work with `UINavigationController` ?

Comment: if not, try `self.window.rootviewcontroller = vc`

Comment: No im not working with UINavigationController. It says property "window"not found on object StartViewcontroller...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the exact same problem and it turned out to be a threading issue. You need to call your presentViewController inside of the following:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
```

Keep in mind, my answer is using Swift, it should be a simple translate back to objective-c though, but I'm pretty sure your running into a threading issue like I was. Hope this helps people.

Comment: Hey Unome. This problem seem to be back in Xcode 8 even though I'm using your code snippets you posted. Do you experience the same problem?

Comment: I haven't been seeing a resurgence of the problem. I'd double check that the conversion to Swift 3 (if your using swift) didn't change anything it wasn't supposed to.

Comment: It works. Thank you, But why?. Is didselect didn't get called on main thread? or there is something else

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
UIView *containerView = self.view.window;
[containerView.layer addAnimation:NO forKey:nil];

UIViewController * otherViewCon = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[self presentViewController:otherViewCon animated:NO completion:nil];
```